# What is the inverse modular of a negative number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm working on Shamir secret sharing and i came across a part where i have

$(-4)^{-1}(\mod 17)$

I have never done negative number using inverse modulus so im kinda stuck

i tried changing it to

$(13)^{-1}(\mod 17)$

but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You've started off fine, and 13 *does* have an inverse modulo 17 since 13 and 17 are coprime. How have you attempted to find it? Having said that, it might be easier to recognize that $-16\equiv 1\pmod{17}$

Comment: ok i think i made a careless mistake along the way resulting in me not getting the value correctly. now it works out fine. thanks for assuring me that im on the right track!

Answer (score 1):

It is actually *better* to keep $-4$, since it's smaller than $13$ and computations will be easier. Since $(-1)^{-1}=-1$, it suffices you compute $4^{-1}$. But $4\times (-4)=-16\equiv 1$. So the inverse of $-4$ will be...?