# Multiplicative Inverse for Elements in an Integer Ring

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, inverse

In the book I'm reading it says that there exist elements with multiplicative inverses in a integer ring if $gcd(a,m)=1$ where $a$ is the element and $m$ is the modulo.

The inverse $a^{-1}$ is defined such that $a \times a^{-1} \equiv 1$ mod $m$

Also it says that if an inverse exist for $a$ we can divide this element since $b/a \equiv b  \times a^{-1}$ mod $m$

I'm confused as to what $b$ is in this case? My guess right now is that it is another member in one of the equivalence classes for the modulos $m$.

Comment: If you're working with *congruences* then $a$ and $b$ are any integers, and $b/a := a^{-1}b$ denotes the (unique) solution of $\,ax\equiv b\pmod{\!m}.\,$ OTOH if you're working with cosets $\,[a] = a+m\Bbb Z\,$ in the quotient ring $\,\Bbb Z/m\,$ then you should already know how to translate between congruences and quotient rings (else you put the cart before horse).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  For example, let $m=7$ and $a=[2]$.  Then $a^{-1}=[4],$ because $2\times4\equiv1\pmod7$.

For another example, if $m=7$ and $a=[3]$ then $a^{-1}=[5],$ because $3\times5\equiv1\pmod7$.

$b$ is any other element.  Say you want to solve for $x$ in $ax\equiv b\pmod m$.

The answer is $x\equiv b\times a^{-1}\pmod m$.

For example, the solution to $2x\equiv5\pmod7$ is $x\equiv5\times2^{-1}\equiv5\times4=20\equiv6\pmod7$.

Comment: I think I understand. So, when we deal with modular arithmetic the inverse of a certain element is completely different from the inverse that we learn in high school math where the inverse of a = 1/a ?

Comment: In the context of real numbers, the inverse of $2$, which could be written $1/2$, is the real number $0.5$; in the context of integers modulo $7$, the inverse of $[2]$, which could be written $1/[2]$, is $[4]$

Comment: @Papaya It's not "completely different". Rather, in both cases $\, a^{-1}$ denotes the solution of $\,ax = 1,\,$ which is [necessarily unique](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3448252/242).